# Advice on postgrad research application (UK, pure maths)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, united-kingdom

I'm looking for advice on postgraduate study in pure maths from academics or people involved in the application process.

I have enjoyed studying pure maths (particularly algebra) throughout my undergrad and masters course, and would like to continue studying it by doing a research based masters or a PhD. Given my grades, I think going straight into a PhD is unrealistic and possibly unwise, so I plan on applying for research-based masters. I got a 2:2 in my undergrad from the University of Bath and a merit in a taught masters from the University of London. In Bath, I never got below 70% in coursework but I really struggled keeping my head in exams. I would get overwhelmed with stress and not be able to do anything properly — I felt like this was the limiting factor for me, not my mathematical ability. Of course, I am aware that I'm not necessarily better than this, I just feel that exams were more a test of holding my nerve rather than how well I can do maths. I genuinely enjoy working on problem sheets and coursework and haven't done badly in those, which is why I want to continue with my studies. If I had received those grades for [decent mathematical effort] I would accept that I'm likely not cut out for a postgrad research programme. I think I would regret not going for it even if I turned out to be no good — at least I'd know for sure that I'm not suited to doing a PhD.

When I went to the University of London, it was during the pandemic and so exams were done from home. I found being in a more relaxed setting with more time helped a bit, and I averaged 69% in these exams.

I have emailed a few departments about this and they aren't responding to me, so any advice you can give would be very welcome. I wanted to contact admissions about my grades before contacting potential supervisors for the research project (to ensure that I'm eligible for the programmes). The entry requirements are usually a 2:1 honours degree, and I think the Merit in my MSc satisfies this.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

TLDR; bad grades due to panicking in exams (2:2), but always got a first in coursework and did pretty well on problem sheets. Would I be considered for a year-long research-based masters in pure maths?

Answer (score 1):

"The entry requirements are usually a 2:1 honours degree, and I think the Merit in my MSc satisfies this." When I was working in the UK, this was correct (to be precise, in my area in my place). Chances are it still is. " I wanted to contact admissions about my grades before contacting potential supervisors for the research project (to ensure that I'm eligible for the programmes)." My advice is to cut that first bit out and contact potential supervisors. My experience is admissions are often not keen on being contacted. Also often you can find eligibility criteria on the web.